# How can I use class="MyCOLUMS" EQUAL TO: class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Instead of using `<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>` can I do this, `<div class="MyCOLUMS"></div>`?

That is `MyCOLUMS` = `col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4`.

If this is possible please explain how this can be achieved? If this approach is wrong please explain why it's wrong.

Comment: You can use only `col-xs-6` instead of `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6` if all resolutions needs same number of columns.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefit do you feel you're gaining from combining the column classes together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to use Bootstrap colums in such a way..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.COLUMS6{
   width: 50%;
}
```

I hope that helped